# Insert into R table from another two table by latest amount from F table search by date with other data from table S mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to pull amount form F table who have latest date & insert into table R where table f code equal table S code & roll, name from table S

Here is my table: F

```
code  amount  datenewfee
111   700    20-September-2019
112   800    25-September-2019
111   700    20-October-2019
112   800    30-October-2019
```

Need to find the latest amount form table F my try was:

```
SELECT amount FROM fee WHERE code = 112 order by str_to_date(datenewfee, '%dd-%MM-%yyyy') desc limit 1
```

table: S

```
roll    name    code 
1120    aaaaa   111
1121    eeeee   111
1122    hhhh    112
1123    bbbb    111
1124    jjjj    112
```

Desired result: table R

```
roll    name    code   amount
1120    aaaaa   111    700
1121    eeeee   111    700
1122    hhhh    112    800
1123    bbbb    111    700
1124    jjjj    112    800
```

i'm trying for single code-111 like:

```
INSERT INTO receivable(roll, name, code, amount)
SELECT roll, name, code, 'amount FROM fee WHERE code = 111 order by str_to_date(`datenewfee`, '%dd-%MM-%yyyy') desc limit 1'
FROM students
WHERE code = 111
```

And for code-112 like:

```
INSERT INTO receivable(roll, name, code, amount)
SELECT roll, name, code, 'amount FROM fee WHERE code = 112 order by str_to_date(`datenewfee`, '%dd-%MM-%yyyy') desc limit 1'
FROM students
WHERE code = 112
```

Please help & ignore my language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can `JOIN` both tables and use `RANK()` to get the latest records in each group of records sharing the same `code`:

```
SELECT roll, name, code, amount
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.roll,
        s.name,
        s.code,
        f.amount,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY f.code ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(f.datenewfee, '%d-%M-%Y') DESC) rk
    FROM fee f
    INNER JOIN students s ON s.code = f.code
) x 
WHERE rk = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can use a crrelated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter on the recent records per group:

```
SELECT
    s.roll,
    s.name,
    s.code,
    f.amount
FROM fee f
INNER JOIN students s ON s.code = f.code
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM fee f1
    WHERE f1.code = f.code 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(f1.datenewfee, '%d-%M-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE(f.datenewfee, '%d-%M-%Y')
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sn5khcvkDVdQtPKi8jGazf/0)**:

Both queries return:

```
| roll | name  | code | amount |
| ---- | ----- | ---- | ------ |
| 1120 | aaaaa | 111  | 700    |
| 1121 | eeeee | 111  | 700    |
| 1122 | hhhh  | 112  | 800    |
| 1123 | bbbb  | 111  | 700    |
| 1124 | jjjj  | 112  | 800    |
```

Comment: thanks, can i use another where if Table: S (Students) have a column 'status' and value 0 or 1